# What i am doing wrong with this code?

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //variable declarations
    int num;

    //clear the listbox
    lstPwrs.Items.Clear();

    //add header to listbox
    lstPwrs.Items.Add("N\tN^2\tN^3");

    //each subsequent line is displayed as N is incremented 
    //use a while loop to do this, as you must be able to create 
    //the proper output for any upper limit the user enters

    //initialize loop variable, then loop
    num = Convert.ToInt32( txtInput.Text );
    while ( num <= 5 )
    ++num;
    {
        lstPwrs.Items.Add( Math.Pow( num, 1 ) + "\t" + Math.Pow( num, 2 ) +
                          "\t" + Math.Pow( num, 3 ) );
    }
}
```

This is what I did and only one line of numbers shows up and also if i enter 5 as my number then everything is done with a base of 6 to each power, Like 6^1, 6^2, 6^3, when 5 is in the text box the answers to those appear. Hope this make sense.

Comment: The compiler should tell you this, no?

Comment: your while loop scope is limited to `++num;`

Comment: you should always use curly braces for all cycles to prevent such mistakes. Also use debugger to know what exactly happens

Comment: i am supposed to have 3 columns that have N^1, N^2, and N^3 and underneath each column i should have 1-5 in in first column to the first power, the second column should be 1-5 to the second power, and the third column should be 1-5 to the third power. now i am just saying five because that is the example i was given, but it should be able to work starting with any number that is entered into the txtbox.

Answer (score 7):

Your `while` syntax is wrong.  It's executing `++num` until `num <= 5` *then* executing the block afterwards.  I think you want:

```
while ( num <= 5 )
{
    ++num;
    lstPwrs.Items.Add( Math.Pow( num, 1 ) + "\t" + Math.Pow( num, 2 ) +
                      "\t" + Math.Pow( num, 3 ) );
}
```

or

```
num = 1;
while ( num <= 5 )
{
    lstPwrs.Items.Add( Math.Pow( num, 1 ) + "\t" + Math.Pow( num, 2 ) +
                      "\t" + Math.Pow( num, 3 ) );
    ++num;
}
```

IF you want to loop from 1 to 5.

Comment: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/0nPwlYKq/

Comment: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/iJxdOwWuXW/                This is what my window is supposed to look like and I am not getting that which is shown in the first link above.

Comment: @user3541892 I don't have access to the linked image - run it in the debugger and see what the intermediate results are in each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Put the code after the loop inside the loop.

```
while ( num <= 5 ){
    ++num;

        lstPwrs.Items.Add( Math.Pow( num, 1 ) + "\t" + Math.Pow( num, 2 ) +
                          "\t" + Math.Pow( num, 3 ) );
}
```

Comment: fileswap.com/dl/0nPwlYKq                                 fileswap.com/dl/iJxdOwWuXW This is what my window is supposed to look like and I am not getting that which is shown in the first link above.